# SQLite3 Database won't load on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, amazon-web-services, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I'm a beginner programmer trying to deploy my first Rails App that uses a local sqlite3 db located at db/production.sqlite3

However, when I deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk, it doesn't seem to load since all my content (stored in the db) doesn't appear. There is no error in the logs, it seems as though it simply ignores the db.

Here is my database.yml file

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
    default: &default
    adapter: sqlite3
    pool: 5
    timeout: 5000

    development:
    <<: *default
    database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
    test:
    <<: *default
    database: db/test.sqlite3

    production:
    <<: *default
    database: db/production.sqlite3
```

I have my db located at db/production.sqlite3 (which is a copy of db/development.sqlite3 - a database that I populated in the dev environment) and when I run a local server with passenger, all seem fine. The content loads with no issues:

```
Started HEAD "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-13 13:52:19 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by HomepageController#index as HTML
  Book Load (4.9ms)  SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE ("books"."release" BETWEEN '2015-04-18 12:52:19.924691' AND '2015-06-12 12:52:19.925430')
   (0.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 30]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 42]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 45]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 48]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 50]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 52]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 53]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 32]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 34]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 40]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 26]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 33]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 36]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 37]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 47]]
  Video Load (2.8ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE ("videos"."uploaded" BETWEEN '2015-04-18 12:52:20.065837' AND '2015-05-13 12:52:20.066244')
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 55]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 58]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 60]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 64]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 66]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 71]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 73]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 74]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 75]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 76]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 77]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 78]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 56]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 61]]
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 62]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 63]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 65]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 67]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 68]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 69]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 70]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 72]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 79]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 80]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 82]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 83]]
   (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 84]]
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_logobanner.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_newsletterform.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_anchornavbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 55]]
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 64]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 60]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 58]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 66]]
  Rendered videos/_operatortalks.html.erb (64.8ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 75]]
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 77]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 71]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 74]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 76]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 73]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 78]]
  Rendered videos/_investortalks.html.erb (8.9ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 56]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 61]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 69]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 63]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 65]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 67]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 68]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 62]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 70]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 72]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 79]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 80]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 82]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 83]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."video_id" = ?  [["video_id", 84]]
  Rendered videos/_othertalks.html.erb (15.9ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 53]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 42]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 50]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 48]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 45]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 52]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 30]]
  Rendered books/_operatorbooks.html.erb (32.3ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 40]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 34]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 32]]
  Rendered books/_investorbooks.html.erb (14.4ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 37]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 36]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 33]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 26]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."book_id" = ?  [["book_id", 47]]
  Rendered books/_otherbooks.html.erb (21.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered homepage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (255.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1377ms (Views: 1134.8ms | ActiveRecord: 18.5ms)
```

When I deploy it to Elastic Beanstalk however, the place where my content should appear is blank. My logs are as follows:

```
=== puma startup: 2015-05-11 21:44:43 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2015-05-11 21:44:43 +0000 ===
[20699] + Gemfile in context: /var/app/current/Gemfile
[20696] - Worker 0 (pid: 20699) booted, phase: 0
[20696] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
[20696] === puma shutdown: 2015-05-11 21:46:22 +0000 ===
[20696] - Goodbye!
=== puma startup: 2015-05-11 21:46:25 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2015-05-11 21:46:25 +0000 ===
[20777] + Gemfile in context: /var/app/current/Gemfile
[20774] - Worker 0 (pid: 20777) booted, phase: 0
Started GET "/" for 85.243.198.164 at 2015-05-11 21:47:16 +0000
Processing by HomepageController#index as HTML
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_logobanner.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_newsletterform.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered shared/_anchornavbar.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered videos/_operatortalks.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered videos/_investortalks.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered videos/_othertalks.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered books/_operatorbooks.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered books/_investorbooks.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered books/_otherbooks.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered homepage/index.html.erb within layouts/application (17.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 24.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

I've seen other people have similar issues and have connected by ssh to the instance and ran "yum install sqlite-devel" but also to no avail.

Does anybody know how I could solve this? I would much prefer not using RDS.

Comment: Do you plan on adding things to the db or will it be read only?

Comment: I think one solution to this problem would be to "dockerize" your app and deploy it on Elastic Beanstalk but as a Docker app. This will give you a self contained environment. Not ideal, since you're a beginner programmer, but this should work.

Comment: Hi Nick, ideally I'd like to be able to add things to the db. Thanks for the help

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion user602525 I wasn't familiar with Docker but I'll have a look at it and give it a go.

Comment: you want to add things to the db, but you understand that scaling or deployments will reset the db, right? I mean, sqlite isn't meant for production-scale.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this @tedder42 thanks for pointing that out. So I'll have to convert my current db to MySql or something similar and then I can use a local db rather than RDS?

Comment: Pedro, running mysql locally will cause some of the same durability problems unless you keep backups and replication logs. What's your objection to RDS?